# Firebase signing in with phone number on another device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What if I want to sign in with phone number on my Android tablet, for instance, using confirmation code, received to my phone. Does this work? How can I allow this or block?

Answer (score 1):

By default it works / allowed . To block you can try `onVerificationCompleted` callback method only without giving manual code input implementation or field to user , it triggers on instant verification or auto-retrieval without user action.